# Language file being loaded from nowhere inbetween constructor and method in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a very strange error occuring. I am loading language files in the constructor of my class and if I exit at the end of the constructor and look at the logs I can see that the last thing to happen is the correct language files being loaded.

If I die at the start of my method though before any code within the method has been run the default language files have been loaded which is overriding the correct ones. If I'm not running any code between the end of the constructor and the start of the method though how is this happening?

Here is my constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->lang->load('application', 'german');
    $this->lang->load('upload', 'german');
}
```

Here is what the logs show:

```
INFO - 2016-02-04 15:05:39 --> Language file loaded: language/german/application_lang.php
INFO - 2016-02-04 15:05:39 --> Language file loaded: language/german/upload_lang.php
INFO - 2016-02-04 15:05:39 --> Helper loaded: language_helper
INFO - 2016-02-04 15:05:39 --> Language file loaded: language/english/tagrisso_lang.php
```

So just to clarify, if I:

- clear the logs
- exit at the end of the constructor

The log only shows the first two lines (the correct language files being loaded).

However if I:

- Clear the logs
- Exit right at the start of my method before any other code

The log shows 4 lines which shows that after the correct language files are loaded the language helper is loaded again and the english file is loaded.

Comment: are there any hooks in app? A hook can be set for `post_controller_constructor`

Comment: Ahhhh it was a hook that was doing it thank you soo much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @charlietfl there was a hook set for `post_controller_constructor` which was loading in the language file again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this?

In `/application/config/config.php` you will find this:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Language
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This determines which set of language files should be used. Make sure
| there is an available translation if you intend to use something other
| than english.
|
*/
$config['language'] = 'english';
```

In `/application/config/autoload.php` you can set default language too.

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Language files
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['language'] = array('lang1', 'lang2');
|
| NOTE: Do not include the "_lang" part of your file.  For example
| "codeigniter_lang.php" would be referenced as array('codeigniter');
|
*/
$autoload['language'] = array();
```

Can you try to change it to German and check again? this will give us enough output about your application configuration.

Perhaps is overwriting your configuration.

Regards.

Comment: I did this and changed it to german but it still just loaded in the english again

Comment: In autoload.php too? Are you extending CI_Controller in other controller? Do you have any helper using language library?

Comment: autoload occurs long before controller is invoked